# precision in python for

Tags: python

I have number f = 2.25e-06 and I want to print it in format

```
 2.250000e-6
```

can someone help?

Comment: Please refer the python manual for str.format specifically [Format String Syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the scientific format

```
print("%e.6" %f)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'{:.6e}'.format(f) # format f exponentially using a base of 6 decimal places
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
print format(a[0]/a[1], '.8f)
```

with the `'8f'` being how many decimal places you want.